# What is a free and simple program to create basic text animation?

Tags: text, animation, video

What I'm looking for is just to have a black background and a word on top of it in white. then break the word to 2 parts, make one part disappear with a fade effect.. some of the free/open source programs don't even have a text tool so it's a must for me.. I've tried Pencil2D, Tupi, Synfig. out of all these Synfig is the closest to what I need but working in it is not fluid. I had a hard time dealing with the text and the animation timeline.

If anyone knows a good program for that I'll be happy to know..
it has to be: 
1. Free 
2. Have a timeline 
3. Have a text tool. 
4. Export as video.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You could use HTML + CSS and a screen recorder :P

Comment: I would go with Synfig, and otherwise PowerPoint ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a program I have used in the past, it was called [VideoPad Video Editor](http://www.nchsoftware.com/videopad/) from NCH Software, it has all the free features you need:

- Add a bank clip
- Add new text clip to project
- Transitions to change from one text clip (the one with the full word) to another (the one with the word cut in half)
- Plus it has a very simple timeline

It's pretty easy to use, it's the easiest I have ever used.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much but I had an issue with this program, it seems you cant edit text after it has been created, I found a better program from NCH following your suggestion (Express Animator) so I you helped me in any case! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Ray well, I am glad you've got things working in your favor.  Ow and btw, you can edit them by double clicking on the word under the video preview. It will open the edit dialog like in my screenshot.  I've tested it before posting the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I didn't catch that when I tested. eventually I went in a completely other way.. powerpoint. I figured it will be a whole lot of work to give an hour of a lecture and sync all the text transitions with the context of the lecture.. so I went with powerpoint and I will not animate the text but have an effect to transition to the next slide. so then I could just go to the next slide manually when i'll be ready in the context of the lecture. I wish I could really do it with animation but it's a tedious work and I got hundreds of words. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I've found for what I was looking for was called ["Express Animate" by NCH software](http://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/index.html) which is also free, I got to it from Alin's suggestion here in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

One good tool I think could work is [Krita](https://krita.org/). It has vectors or text animation including vectors for artistic, multiline, & calligraphy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've downloaded it and gave it a shot but it's not the best for what I need. I also asked a question in their support and 2 people said it's not the best for that job: https://krita-artists.org/t/how-can-i-animate-text-objects/11083/2 Thanks for trying anyway.